# The control key appears to act like it is being pressed when it is not

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

As I use my machine, especially writing on boards such as this, and I depress the <kbd>D</kbd> key in a word, for example, the add bookmark prompt will popup.  Sometimes it will start zooming in and out as if I am using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with the scroll wheel. And when I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it will erase the entire word.  Earlier advice (I could had sworn I had asked this here) was to format Windows.

Instead, I got a new computer, with a fresh copy of Windows 7 installed on it.  And lo and behold, the problem did not go away.  I did replace the keyboard.  Replaced the mouse.  This is more of an inconvenience over anything and I have not heard of any other folks complaining about this issue (I work in IT).  And I am flummoxed as to why this keeps happening to me.

Not too sure what else it can be.  My only recourse when this does occur is to strike the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key a few times then the problem will go away for the time being.  However, it does come back.  Either five minutes later, or an hour, or a week and a half.  There is really no pattern as to when I notice this, however, it seems to happen most often in a web browser opposed to a word processor.

Comment: Have you checked your **Ease of Access Center** settings in Control Panel?  You might have accidentally activated the Sticky Keys option.

Comment: I assume you mean under making keyboard easier to use?  Nothing is ticked besides **toggle keys for num lock**, and **prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moving to the edge**.  Sticky keys is not enabled.

Comment: What language is listed when you go to Region and Language, then Keyboards and Languages, then Change Keyboards?

Comment: English (United States)

Comment: I have the same problem, and it is not bound to a single computer, or operating system and not even to a single keyboard, i experienced it on probably any usb keyboard i used, windows mac linux gentoo, ubuntu.. everything. So i have come to the conclusion that it's a common problem maybe in some chip inside the keyboards, and most people don't notice it because they don't need the "strange characters", those where you need to press 2 or 3 control keys to get them.